# JComboBox in Jtable doesn't stop editing on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a `Jtable` with 10 rows and 2 columns.

Column nb 2 is a `JCombobox` which is editable.

When i manually enter some values in `JCombobox` and when i  hit enter than that value is persisted.

But when i put some value in `JCombobox` and click with mouse to some other cell than that value is assigned to that cell not to the cell which i am actually editing.

Basically it doesn't stop editing the cell when focus is lost from that cell.

It stops editing when i click on the next cell and new value is assigned to that cell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is class of the options for the JComboBox? String? Or a customized object?

Comment: @BOND class is String for JComboBox

Comment: Can you show what you have implemented? What table cell editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a focus listener on your `JCombobox` component and by focus lost you should stop editing in the table cell editor. For example:

```
public class TestTableCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor 
                                      implements FocusListener {
private JComboBox comboBox;

public TestTableCellEditor(JComboBox comboBox) {
   this.comboBox = comboBox;
   comboBox.addFocusListener(this);       
}
// ... Some other things in the editor

public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
// You don't need to do anything here
}
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {        
    stopCellEditing();        
}
}
```